# I'm fairly new to python coding so I'm trying to challenge myself to do elif statements and I can't find how to fix this problem

Tags: python

So here is my code and I can't see what causes the error.

```
foods = int(input("What is your favorite food?: "))

if foods == apple:
    print("you like fruits!")
elif foods == pork:
    print("you like meat!")
elif foods == egg:
    print("you like poultry!")
```

The error is

```
line 3, in <module>
    foods = int(input("What is your favorite food?: "))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'egg:'
```

Does anyone have any idea how to fix this?

Comment: And what _did_ you expect `int("egg:")` to do?

Comment: Remove the `int()`, put quotes around `foods == 'apple'`…?!

Comment: your asking for a number input and expecting a string. Also there isnt quotes around the foods. if you put quotes around apple, pork, and egg, and also get rid of int it should work

Comment: well, I was expecting int("egg:") to be a response to the question "What is your favorite food?"

Comment: You're trying to turn whatever you're inputting into an int, a number. "egg:" obviously has no meaning as a number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The int part in the int(input("What is your favorite food?: ")) line tries to convert the input string "egg" into an integer, which it can´t. Remove it and the problem will go away.

Also, after the if == or elif ==, you need to write the food type as "egg", "pork", "apple", otherwise python think you are referring to an variable and not a specific string.

Good luck!